# How to replace \ with / in the full path of my files listed using a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, subdirectory

Suppose on my Windows machine I have a folder named `root`. Inside this folder I have about 10 subfolders named `Mathematics`, `Physics`, `Chemistry`, etc and inside each of these subfolders, I have about 30 subsubfolders like `John-doe`, `Sara-smith`, `Nicola-sheperd`, etc and also inside each of these subsubsubfolders I have about 6-7 files with different extensions such as `.png`,`.jpg` `.pdf`, `.tex`, `.idx`, `.txt`, `.aux`, etc.
To list all `pdf` files in all folders, I'm using the following batch file:

```
@echo off
for /r %%F in (*.pdf) do echo %%~dpF%%~nxF >>dir.txt
```

But it has one problem:

It shows me the full path like `E:\root\mathematics\john-doe\paper.pdf` while **for some reason** I want it to be `E:/root/mathematics/john-doe/paper.pdf`
**How can I replace `\` with `/`?**

Answer (score 1):

To replace `\` with `/`, use [string replacement](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.Replace).  If you do this within your `for` loop, you'll need delayed expansion as well.  Do `setlocal /?` from a console for more info.  For what it's worth, `%%~dpF%%~nxF` is the hard way of saying `%%~fF`.  See the last couple of pages of `for /?` in a console for more info.

```js
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

>dir.txt (
    for /r "E:\root" %%I in (*.pdf) do (
        set "file=%%~fI"
        echo !file:\=/!
    )
)
```

Comment: It replaces `\` with `/`, but your code adds additional stuff like `E:\root>(
set "file=E:\root\mathematics\john-doe\paper.pdf"  
 echo !file:\=/! 
)` to the `dir.txt`. How can I delete them?

Comment: I think you missed including the `@echo off` when you copypasted my code.  I just tested it and it works perfectly here.

Comment: No, I didn't miss to include `@echo off`. Please help me.

Comment: @Sisabe Did you run the code exactly as it is?  The `>dir.txt` has to be attached to an independent parentheses pair.  If you tried moving it to the end of the `for` loop (as in `for /r... do (set "file=%%~fI" & echo !file:\=/! )>dir.txt`), that would cause the symptom you describe.  If that doesn't help, then remove `>dir.txt` and on the `echo !file:\=/!` line add `>>dir.txt` as you had before.

Comment: "Did you run the code exactly as it is?" Yes. "If that doesn't help, ...." I did this, but in this way, it shows me only `\=/ `! Nothing else.

Comment: Can you edit your question above, copying your script and pasting it at the bottom of the question saying "I've tried this, but I get" ... whatever it is you get as a result?